# QT 5.3 QListView column problems

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

guys! I'm newbie in QT Programming.
I want to ask, why columns is appearing as usual row on my QListView control?

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 1, ui->listView);

QList<QStandardItem*> items;
items.append(new QStandardItem("Column 1"));
model->insertColumn(0, items);

ui->listView->setModel(model);
```

Comment: You could try to set the flow property to `QListView::TopToBottom` with `QListView::setFlow()`.

Comment: http://rghost.net/56689249/image.png look at this, these columns are showing like a usual items.

Comment: I think it is because you are using a QListView, if you want to see columns you should use a QColumnView oder write an approriate Model for your view

Comment: Yeah, but how i can make multi-column listview like in windows os?

Comment: Use the model-view principle of Qt. See here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/model-view-programming.html or an example  (for Qt 4.7) here: http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/modelview/

Answer (score 0):

QListView simply can not display multiple columns. Use QTableView.